# Clumsy function in Powershell - ideas to make it succinct?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have just written a simple function in Powershell

```
Function Get-Stage
{       
    $myEnv = Get-Environment
    $devEnvs = "D","Dev","Test","T"
    $prodEnvs = "P","U","PTA","B"
    if($devEnvs -contains $myEnv)
    {
        return "D"
    }
    elseif($prodEnvs -contains $myEnv)
    {
        return "P"          
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

`Get-Environment` is a function that reads the registry to find the environment text which can be any string value listed in `$devEnvs` and `$prodEnvs`. The function will just return either a `D` or a `P` based on what is returned from `Get-Environment`

I don't like it. Is there a nice readable, concise way to write it that you can think of?

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the function is? What does `Get-Environment` do? What inputs and outputs do you expect from this function?

Comment: what is Get-Environment doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, questions on better ways to write code is very much based on different opinions, but you could do something like the following:

```
function Get-Stage
{
    $environment = Get-Environment

    switch ($environment)
    {
        {$PSItem -in "D","Dev","Test","T"}{
            Write-Output "D"
        }
        {$PSItem -in "P","U","PTA","B"}{
            Write-Output "P" 
        }
        default{
            Write-Error "Invalid environment value in registry ('$PSItem')"
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to support PowerShell v2, just change the switch statement to the following:

```
switch ($environment)
{
    {"D","Dev","Test","T" -contains $_}{
        Write-Output "D"
    }
    {"P","U","PTA","B" -contains $_}{
        Write-Output "P" 
    }
    default{
        Write-Error "Invalid environment value in registry ('$_')"
    }
}
```

Comment: Robert I'm using powershell 2, I guess this solution won't work with that? $PSItem is v3 onwards, is that right?

Comment: Updated my answer to include support for v2. If you want to support dynamic list loading, however, look at the solution suggested by @Neolisk.

Answer (score 2):

Does this make it any better?

```
Function Get-Stage
{       
  $myEnv = Get-Environment;

  $envDict = @{
     "D" = @("Dev","Test","T");
     "P" = @("U","PTA","B")
  };

  $envDict.Keys | foreach {
    $envs = @($_) + $dict[$_];
    if($envs -contains $myenv) { return $_; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually looks slightly harder to read. Maybe my simple solution isn't so bad after all.

Comment: @MooMinTroll: Supposed to be more maintainable, however. There is no duplication of anything - code or data. You only need to extend the part where it says `$envDict`, which can even be an XML file, so the person who maintains it needs no knowledge of Powershell.